# show range sliders value as val input (for item range sliders)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rangeslider

this is my range slider : [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yukunagedi/1/edit)

HTML :

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
```

JS :

```
var items =[ 'student','bachelor','masterstudent',' PHD'];
var s = $("#slider");

s.slider({
  min:1,
  max:items.length
});

var oneBig = 100 / (items.length - 1);

$.each(items, function(key,value){
  var w = oneBig;
  if(key === 0 || key === items.length-1)
  w = oneBig/2;
  $("#legend").append("<label style='width: "+w+"%'>"+value+"</laben>");
});
```

CSS :

```
label{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
label:first-child{
  text-align:left;
}
label:last-child{
  text-align:right;
}
```

how can show the labels in this range sliders as val input like this one [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qibiyakaqi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: WHat out put you want exactely, because there are only strings in your code

Comment: i want to show value inside input. when slide to second item, bachelor appear inside input as val. like  http://jsbin.com/qibiyakaqi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @fraweb (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html) check this link..and see range_45

Comment: i want to show limitation for degree of Education by range slider.

Comment: no @Astro, i used ui jquery

Comment: there is no way to do this!!???

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f7df66e3-a317-42ef-8784-0c9950c1161b/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items =[ 'student','bachelor','masterstudent',' PHD'];

var s = $("#slider");
var oneBig = 100 / (items.length - 1);
s.slider({
  min:1,
  max:items.length,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var curr_val = ui.value - 1;
    $( "#legend input").val('');
    $( "#legend #input"+curr_val).val(items[curr_val]);
  }
});

$.each(items, function(key,value){
  var w = oneBig;
  if(key === 0 || key === items.length-1)
    w = oneBig/2;
  $("#legend").append("<input id='input"+key+"' style='width: "+w+"%' />");
});
$( "#legend #input0").val(items[0]);
```

```css
label{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
label:first-child{
  text-align:left;
}
label:last-child{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```